# Before filter in angularjs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am building a website where users can view posts.

The posts are publicly available. The requirement is that i need to check whether the user is logged in on every user action.

For example, a user hits my website url www.mysite.com and views a post. The user is not logged in at this point. The user tries to like the post.
Before the method for like is executed, i need to execute a method to check if the user is logged in. If not logged in, show login box.
Same is the case for all user actions.

```
function likePost() {
   checkUserLogin();
   ...
}

function commentPost() {
   checkUserLogin();
   ...
}
```

Is there a better way to do this in angularjs. Something like 'beforefilter' in rails?

Comment: Did you try "$broadcast" thing?

Comment: I am new to angularjs..  Can you provide a sample code?